# GAE Custom domain mapping failure after adding SSL Wildcard certificate

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have three projects in Google App Engine, each of them have a custom sub-domain name mapped to it like this:

- Project A: projecta.domain.com
- Project B: projectb.domain.com
- Project C: projectc.domain.com

That worked very well until we added a wildcard ssl-certificate to Project A. Suddenly all three subdomains are mapped to Project A.

They appeared under Project A, custom domains (Project A->App Engine->Settings->Custom Domains) and not one under each Project B and Project C, and when browsing to projectb.domain.com and projectc.domain.com, we get content from projecta.domain.com and not from b and c.

We have tried this but none of it fixes the problem:

- Removed the SSL-certificate
- Removed all custom domains and added them again
- Disabled all projects, removed all domains, added them again
  and enabled the projects
- Logged in as different users, verify the domain again, add/remove etc

Two more notes:

- We also have a fourth project, Project D (projectd.domain.com), which strange enough has not been affected and still works.
- When trying to add a custom domain under project B or C (Project [B/C]->App Engine->Settings->Custom Domains), clicking on Add button does not give any response at all. Checking network, the click performs a call to Console servers, and when checking Project A (App Engine->Settings->Custom Domains), the custom domain name has appeared there instead.

**Edit 1:**
After deleting all custom domains in every project, when trying to add custom domain projectb.domain.com to Project B, we get this error message "This domain points to another app. If you point it to this app, the other app will stop working." But it does not appear in any another app. After confirming domain is not added.

**Edit 2:**
After deleting all custom domains in every project, when adding projectb.domain.com to Project B first, nothing appears. But when adding projecta.domain.com to Project A afterwards, both projectb and projecta appears under Project B. And when trying to delete projecta from projectb, we get the error message "Error. Failed to delete mapping.". Something is really wrong here.

Does anyone know how to access the domain mappings settings in any other way? It seams like the domain mapping data has been corrupted and we are stucked.

**Edit 3:**
For some unknown reason everything worked again after 8 hours of trying and failing, and I have no idea why. Suddenly I could delete all custom domains and when I added them they appear under the correct project. I've tried the exact same thing several times before. However, when I now add the SSL-certificate again **every custom domain mapping moved by itself from their own project to the very project I added the SSL certificate to**. Can somehow the SSL-certificate change the domain mappings?

Comment: Are the projects still working if accessed via the `appspot.com` domain?

Comment: Was the custom domain mapping for any of the projects initially done via Google Apps?

Comment: Yes, projecta-domain-com.appspot.com and projectb-domain-com.appspot.com is working, but not projectc-domain-com.appspot.com for some reason

Comment: No all domain mappings were done inside the Google app engine console

Comment: Try to actually access the domain claimed to still be mapped (in the last edit), then check logs for all apps - if indeed one of them shows log entries matching the access then re-check that app's config. If it still doesn't show the mapping then it's obviously a bug of some sort as it did act as if it would be mapped.

Comment: I'd suggest filing an issue report using the Send feedback (`!`) bubble on the console's toolbar or on the GAE issues page: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3

Comment: Thank you Dan, I happened to do Edit 3 before I got a chance to try your suggestion two steps above. And thanks, I'll try to send feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution! There is a bug in Google App Engine Console when adding custom domains and connect to a ssl-certificate in different project right after each other.

**ADDING CUSTOM DOMAINS**

*Steps to reproduce the bug:*

1. Select a project in the toolbar
2. Goto App Engine->Settings->Custom Domains and after pressing "Add Custom Domain", add a sub-domain and press "Add"
3. Nothing happens, but when going back to "Custom Domains" the new subdomain appears there
4. Change project in the toolbar
5. Click on "Custom Domains", press "Add Custom Domain"
6. Add a sub-domain and press "Add"

The domain added in step 6 is now in fact mapped to the project selected in step 1.

*Workaround*

Make a page refresh in the browser between step 5 and 6.

**CONNECT SEVERAL PROJECT TO WILDCARD SSL-CERTIFICATE**

*Steps to reproduce the bug*

1. After uploading a Wildcard SSL-certificate
2. Select a project in the toolbar
3. Goto App Engine->Settings->SSL Certificate
4. Click on your SSL-certificate, then check the domain and press "Save"
5. Change project in the toolbar
6. Click on "SSL Certificate",
7. Click on your SSL-certificate, then check the domain and press "Save"

The custom domain previously connected to the project selected in step 5 is now added to the project selected in step 2.

*Workaround*

Make a page refresh in the browser between step 6 and 7.

Comment: Thank you very much for Workaround. The google need to fix it as soon as possible, big bug!