# AppEngine console add custom domain bug?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have 2 projects in AppEngine with 2 custom domains

Example

```
website1
website2
```

**The custom domains are already verified and added to Google account**

When I try to add custom domain in `website1` project, example *www.website1.com*, it works, then I select `website2` project, when I try to add the domain `website2.com` it is added in another project (`website1`)

and two strange things happens, first the domain `website2.com` will open the website of the `website1` project, and suddenly the both domains show the message

`The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.`

Since the domain `website2.com` was added to wrong project (`website1`), if I try to add the `website2.com` inside the `website2` project, it asks if I want to overwrite the settings because the domain `website2.com` is used by another application (`website1`), I choose yes but nothing happens!

I followed all the instructions from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application and from the AppEngine console, **IT WORKED**, but when I try do manage other domains this strange behavior happens

So, The AppEngine is inserting the custom domain in wrong project

I guess this is a BUG in AppEngine console or not? what's wrong?

Comment: Potentially related to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141886/gae-custom-domain-mapping-failure-after-adding-ssl-wildcard-certificate

Comment: This is really a bug, the post you provided has the solution! Thank you